# How to clear text in a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, files

How to clear text that existed in a text file without opening it?

I mean for example I have a file as `hello.txt` with some text data in it, and how can I clear the total text in that file **without opening it?**

By this, I mean not using any editor like nano, Gedit, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by 'opening' a file? In all the answers given so far the file will still be opened for writing by the shell. In the end the shell is just a program like any other.

Comment: @Jeff not using any thing like nano , gedit etc.

Comment: Hus787  I have not typed from getting there if you think so else  I welcome your interest in my question.

Comment: I agree with Jeff's comment... I too have opinion* that the file stream has to be opened to write to it, whether you use any text editors, or redirection. (_*appreciate anybody suggedting links to help with the matter_)

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Just open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and type as

```
 > hello.txt
```

that's it, your data in that file will be cleared with out opening it even .

Example:

[image]

Comment: Technically the file will be opened.  Just not in an editor.

Comment: Is there a way to undo this command?

Comment: @Rao , If its a large like >10GB , may be. But how much extent not sure.

Comment: @souravc  John is correct, the file will be open. Shell opens a file for redirection `>` with flags `O_WRITE|O_TRUNC`. In fact, this is stated in the `bash` manual explicitly under Redirecting Output section: "If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size."

Answer (score 54):

The easiest way is to truncate a file is to redirect the output of the shell no-op command (`:`) to the file you want to erase.

```
: > hello.txt
```

Comment: Its probably not the easiest (relative to just `>`) but the fastest for sure..i wonder why it has not been mentioned in any of the answers of this highly viewed question..here, take +1..

Comment: This works with zsh too (accepted answer doesn't work)

Answer (score 32):

I have to do this all the time with log files. The easiest way I have found is with the following command:

```
cat /dev/null > hello.txt
```

This deletes allo of the content of the file, and leaves you with an empty file without having to open it  in an editor, select text,  any of that stuff. More specifically what it does is to replace the contents of the file with the contents of "/dev/null", or nothing. It's pretty slick, actually.

The only caveat is that the user you are currently logged in as must have write permission to said file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please add an example so that it can look more nicely.+1

Answer (score 15):

I am also going to use redirection like rajagenupula's answer. But there is a little more flexibility. Open a terminal and type,

```
cat > hello.txt
```

And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. It will wipe out the previous file. If you want upto this much it is fine.

If you wish you can do something more after wiping the file. In this way not only you can wipe a file without opening but also you can write a few lines with proper formatting in the file. Say you wish to write "Ubuntu is the best OS" after wiping the file, just do

```
cat > hello.txt
Ubuntu is the 
best OS
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Now the previous file is wiped out. At the same time words are there in two lines as I put them.

See the example:

[image]

Comment: hey thank you for answering. so little but work to be done right after that also & but still interesting .+1

Comment: `>` stands for redirection. `cat > file` will write `stdout` to file, overwriting any existing file.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach - `cp` the `/dev/null` to the file

```
xieerqi:$ cat testFile.txt                                                                                        
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      115247656 83100492  26269816  76% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             2914492        4   2914488   1% /dev
tmpfs             585216     1152    584064   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2926072    98096   2827976   4% /run/shm
none              102400       76    102324   1% /run/user

xieerqi:$ cp /dev/null testFile.txt                                                                               

xieerqi:$ cat testFile.txt

xieerqi:$
```

Why does this work and how does this work ? The `testFile.txt` will be opened  with `O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC` flags, which means if the file exists - it will be truncated, which means contents discarded and size set to zero. This is the same flag with which `>` operator in shell opens the file on the right of that operator.

Next, `cp` will attempt to read from `/dev/null` and after reading 0 bytes will simply close both files, thus leaving `testFile.txt` truncated and contents effectively deleted.

Knowing that, we could in theory use anything that allows us to open a file with `O_TRUNC`. For instance this:

```
dd of=testFile.txt count=0
```

Small difference here is that `dd` won't perform any `read()` at all. Big plus of this `dd` version is that it is POSIXly portable. The [dd specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dd.html) state:

> If the seek= expr conversion is not also specified, the output file shall be truncated before the copy begins if an explicit of= file operand is specified, unless conv= notrunc is specified.

By contrast `cp /dev/null testFile.txt` isn't necessarily portable, since [POSIX specifications for cp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cp.html) cover what happens only if source_file is non-regular and when `-r`/`-R` flags are specified (big thanks to [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt) for pointing this out), but not what happens when `-r` or `-R` are omitted, which is the case here. However it appears at least GNU `cp` defaults to using rule 3 in the same spec, which is truncating the existing file without changing its type.

Comment: you are awesome man !

Answer (score 6):

## Not the shortest answer but...

This answer is based on another from [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/634217/662962). Although not the shortest bash command, `truncate` is the most readable for average newbies:

```
$ echo Hello > Hello.txt
$ echo World! >> Hello.txt
$ cat Hello.txt
Hello
World!
$ truncate -s 0 Hello.txt
$ ll Hello.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rick rick 0 Mar 20 17:32 Hello.txt
```

Parameters used with `truncate` command here:

- "-s" set the size
- "0" size will be zero

## Clear everything except first 10,000 bytes

An advantage of `truncate` is you can specify how much to keep, not just zero:

```
$ truncate -s 10000 Hello.txt
```

... will truncate everything after the first 10,000 bytes. This could be useful if a program went crazy and dumped many Megabytes of data into a small log file:

- Run the `truncate` command for a reasonable larger normal size of 10K
- Open the file with your text editor and press <kbd>End</kbd>
- Highlight and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to delete the remaining bytes that don't belong (usually recognizable by ASCII garbage characters).

Comment: truncate is useful, case: sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/int/*/syslog.*

Comment: i think truncate will fail on myltibytes chars content in file (

Answer (score 5):

If a file was created with the name **hello.txt** and was provided with some texts then the below command in terminal<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> will remove all the text in the *hello.txt* file,

```
echo "" > hello.txt
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering , +1. expand it with some example please so it can be look more nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
vi filename -c ':1,$d' -c ':wq'
```

worked the best for me because of the particular permission it had

Comment: You can improve this answer by elaborating on the problem you had. Also you could explain what the program `vi` is and what the various parameters and arguments do.

Answer (score 0):

So, I see a lot of redirections being used to answer this ;)

A little different approach with the combo: ***rm & touch***

```
rm hello.txt && touch hello.txt
```

<sup>(*yeah... yet another cheat!*)</sup>

So with this command combo *the file hello.txt wasn't opened* and in the end you still have file hello.txt in its place with the contents cleared. Just like you wanted!

Comment: Not a good 'cheat' in my opinion, it can change file permissions...

Comment: This might be better of deleted. It can lead to problems: permisions can change. If done on a log file it can lead to unexpected behaviour from the service that expects the log to be there and to be writable.

Comment: While this answer is not the best way as a point of interest: To correct the issues with owner/permission first check the ownership and permissions then append this(adjust as required): && sudo chown user:group hello.txt && sudo chmod 644 hello.txt

Comment: inode number will be deleted. a new inode number will be created. bad idea.

Comment: WARNING, need to copy/print permissions firstly before exec that !!!!!!!