# Clearing the file by cat > filename

Tags: command-line

The files may be cleared using 
`cat /dev/null > filename`. Is it the same special file that is working whenever `cat > filename` is done?

Comment: Why not empty it by `touch filename`?

Comment: @Pilot6 `touch filename` creates a 0-length file named `filename` if `filename` is not present, but if `filename` is present it will just update its `mtime` attribute (last modification time)

Comment: `> filename` also clears the file

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No.

These are two different techniques of [Clearing a text file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390167/how-to-clear-text-in-a-file) using `cat /dev/null > file` and 
`cat > file` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

[Redirection `>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) is used to redirect output to some file. For example `date` will show the current time and date on [std out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)

```
$ date
Sat Jul 25 20:56:09 IST 2015
```

If you use,

```
$ date>/path/to/file
```

Then it will redirect `stdout` to `file`.

```
$ cat /path/to/file
Sat Jul 25 20:56:23 IST 2015
```

**How `cat /dev/null>file` clears the content of file**

It just redirect the content of null device [`/dev/null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) to the file. So the contents are overwritten and it becomes empty.

**How `cat > file` clears the content of file**

`cat` Concatenate file(s), or standard input, to standard output. Take the following example,

```
$ cat
some text          # by user on stdin
some text          # stdin to stdout concatenated by cat
some other text    # by user on stdin
some other text    # stdin to stdout concatenated by cat
^C                 # Ctrl+C to terminate.
```

The command `cat > file` will wait for stdin and will redirect and overwrite the file. It need to be stopped using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

If you do not enter anything into the stdin and terminate the process with 
SIGINT (`Ctrl+C`) it will overwrite the file with a blank.

The following example is there for more clarification:

```
$ cat > file
some text
some other text
^C
$ cat file
some text
some other text
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite right, cat > filename is not using a here-doc.  Pretty sure that you only get a heredoc when you use << ....

Answer (score 1):

No special file has any useful purpose in either case.

`cat /dev/null` is exactly a no-op, this command does absolutely nothing of interest and it can be replaced by any command that doesn't output anything.

You can for example clear a file's content with any of these commands:

```
printf > filename
true > filename
: > filename
```

or even, with many shells, by using no command at all but the redirection:

```
> filename
```

On the other hand:

```
cat > filename
```

is redirecting `stdin`, i.e. everything you type on your keyboard, to filename. If you interrupt the `cat` command before typing anything, the result would also be an empty file but that is a quite inefficient method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No, what is clearing the file is not `/dev/null`, but the `>` redirection, which intrinsically truncates the output file itself before redirecting the output of `cat`.

- `cat /dev/null > filename`: you're opening `/dev/null` and printing its "content" (nothing) to `stdout`; at the same time a file descriptor for `filename` is opened, the file is truncated and the `stdout` of `cat` is redirected to it (hence nothing is actually redirected to the file)
- `cat > filename`: you're printing nothing to `stdout`, because you're not specifying a file and you're not even passing `stdin` (which has the effect of making `cat` waiting undefinetly); at the same time a file descriptor for `filename` is opened, the file is truncated and the `stdout` of `cat` is redirected to it (hence nothing is actually redirected to the file)

They do exactly the same thing (in terms of clearing the file) but the first opens an extra file descriptor compared to the second and the second will wait undefinetly for something to come into `cat`'s `stdin`.

Methods equivalent to the first one (and to the second one result-wise, but without the hassle of the undefinetly waiting `cat`) would be:

```
$ echo -n | cat > file # empty pipe
$ <emptyfile cat > file # empty file
$ <<<'' cat > file # empty herestring
$ <<EOF cat > file
>EOF # empty heredoc
```

Comment: @souravc I don't understand your point, what are you trying to say? It indeed doesn't print anything to `stdout`, for a reason or for another. However it doesn't "use heredocs", the point is `cat > filename` just waits until "something happens" (which is not really clear to me about what it is) but it's not restricted to an empty herdoc, you could also use an empty file (`<emptyfile cat > out`) an empty herestring (`<<<"" cat > filename`) or an empty pipe (`echo -n | cat > filename`)

Comment: @souravc Actually thinking about it twice I know what it is: the point is that the `stdin` file descriptor is not opened at all in `cat > filename`, while it is in all the other methods (and `stdin` always contains an empty string).

Comment: yes I got your point. When tested the command I did not found any temporary file associated with the process. If it would be a heredoc it must accompany some temp file.